# Stone veneer fireplace with TV mount and mantle

Tags: basement, fireplace, television, stone, veneer

I'm currently attempting to create a "stone" accent wall where I plan on installing a fireplace mantel and TV mount.

I purchased and hung cement board to my frame and came across a few conversation / videos which at best, befuddled me.

**1) Metal Lath:** It seems as though some products don't require one. They simply attach the stone to the wall using said "glue/mortar" and its good to go. I'm going to have kids running around this thing, so It can't fall apart.

**2) TV Mount:** Some people attach the mount to the Cement board and put stone around it, others screw through the stone.

**3) Mantel:** Same as the tv mount, mantel first and stone after?

Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: If _your_ stone veneer product cal for metal lathe, then you'd best use it. If it doesn't call for it, you're wasting money at best, and possibly making a poor install if you do use it. Follow _your_ directions.

Answer (score 1):

If you use actual cement board, actual mortar, and actual stone, it will hold together due to a chemical reaction that basically turns the stone, mortar, and rock into a single piece of rock.  Just make sure NOT to use too much water in the mortar.  It should be almost like playdough.  The biggest mistake people make with mortar (and other cement) is making it thin like vomit.  Make sure to wipe the cement board with a wet sponge before placing the rock on it.

Once everything is together and hardened you can drill into the rock facing and use concrete anchors if you want.  That is what I would do in case I ever wanted to remove the TV mount and replace it with a different one.

This job can be easier if you buy stone that has been rock-sawn in half (so that the "back side" going against the cement board is smooth)

Answer (score 1):

If it’s a floating mantle, I would recommend installing stone around the mantle. You can make a template the size of your mantle with scrap wood and install it onto the cement board. Then butt your stone right up to it. Once you’re done and the cement is completely dried, remove the template and install your mantle.